# Whitespaces in tabularx added after \extracolsep

Tags: spacing, tabularx

I'm quite new to Tex, but I did some tutorials and I'm stuck now, after googling didn't help anymore.

My code:

```
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.75}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline 
    \textbf{col 1} &  & col 3 & col 4 & & col 6
    \\
    \hline
    some stuff & & & & other stuff & 
    \\
    \hline
    text thats pretty & & & & important & 
    \\
    \hline

    \multicolumn{5}{r|}{combined } & \\ \cline{6-6}
\end{tabularx}
\egroup
```

My problem looks like this:

[image]

I don't know, how to fix it. I'm used to HTML's simplicity by using "width: 100%;" and then the columns auto-resize. How could I manage to get something similar in Tex?

Comment: You're getting a paragraph indent. You need should place a `\noindent` before the first `\bgroup`.

Comment: Doesn't really change something. Neither using `\noindent{}` nor just `\noindent`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean that the `\noindent` would fix how the `\cline` works.  The `\cline` is being effected by the extra space thrown in between the columns by `\extracolsep{\fill}`

Comment: `l` type columns don't resize. You need `tabularx`' `X` columns. (With `X` columns only `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` won't have an effect but all columns will have the same width)

Comment: HTML and typography are not the same thing. It's not in general desirable to stretch a table to cover the entire line width, but this much depends on the nature of the table.

Comment: Could you edit the question title to make it more specific? This will help other people find this question and any solutions below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the `tabularx` environment but you're not including any expandable columns.  So `tabularx` is trying to fill the table to the width of `\textwidth` but can't find any columns to expand.

The `tabularx` environment gives you the ability to create *exapandable* columns.  They're marked by `X` in the column declaration.  These column expand to fill up the available space provided by the specified width for the environment.  The expanded columns are treated as a `\parbox` of the width expanded to.

So should pick a column that will be expandable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.75}%
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l |  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l | l | l | l | X |}
    \hline 
    \textbf{col 1}    &  & col 3 & col 4 &             & col 6    \\\hline
    some stuff        &  &       &       & other stuff &          \\\hline
    text thats pretty &  &       &       & important   &          \\\cline{6-6}

    \multicolumn{5}{r|}{combined } &                              \\\cline{6-6}
\end{tabularx}
\egroup

\end{document}
```

You're not restricted to only one expandable column.  You can specify as many as you want.  For example,

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l |  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}  X | X | X | X | X |}
```

You'll want the `\noindent` in the front of the group to prevent any indentation of a paragraph you would be getting otherwise.

Per @egreg 's comment, the content of this table doesn't seem to warrant filling the entire width of the page.  Something like the following seems like it should work decently for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\hspace*{\fill}
\bgroup
\def\arraystretch{1.75}%
\begin{tabular}{ | l |  l | l | l | l | l |}
    \hline 
    \textbf{col 1}    &  & col 3 & col 4 &             & col 6    \\\hline
    some stuff        &  &       &       & other stuff &          \\\hline
    text thats pretty &  &       &       & important   &          \\\cline{6-6}

    \multicolumn{5}{r|}{combined } &                              \\\cline{6-6}
\end{tabular}
\egroup
\hspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Terrific explanation! concise for so much information.