# White spaces between column in tabular (and tabularx)

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have the same problem as in [Whitespaces in tabularx added after \extracolsep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123927/whitespaces-in-tabularx-added-after-extracolsep), but the solution does not work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{\fill}
\begin{table*}[ht!]
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} llllll}
\toprule \rowcolor{light-gray} 
Test  & Test & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2 \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ side\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular}&  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2 \end{tabular} \\ \midrule
1 & X   & X     & X & 0  & X         & X           \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\hspace*{\fill}

\end{document}
```

As the title is a bit too long so I divided into two rows. The output is like this:[image: here]

Please can anyone help how can I fill the white spaces.

P.S: replacing tabular* with *tabularx* produces the same output.

Comment: your title asks about `tabularx` but your example uses `tabular*` which is a completely different environment. Which do you want to ask about?

Comment: your example produces the error `! Undefined control sequence. l.9     \toprule`

Comment: @davidcarlisle edited. it's tabular not tabularx, get confused with another table myself. but the package behaves quite the same

Comment: white space is introduced by `@{\extracolsep{\fill}} `, i suggest you to use `tabularx` .

Comment: @zarko using tabularx does not make a difference. tabular* and tabularx behaves pretty much the same.

Comment: no, between them is big difference ...

Comment: @zarko, does not matter, the output is the same, problem not solved.

Comment: How (or where) are `\belowrulesepcolor` and `\aboverulesepcolor` defined? How or where is the color `light-grey` defined? Why does your contain an `\end{table*}` instruction without a corresponding `\begin{table*}` instruction? Are you really just asking us to perform basic debugging on your code?

Comment: @mico the light gray was only to show the white spaces, otherwise you can't actually see the white spaces. \begin{table*} was only accidentally deleted. there's no such thing as debugging code here just on how to fill the white spaces, isn't that the title of the question to begin with?

Comment: @Sharah `tabularx` and `tabular*` are not at all the same, the method for controlling the table width is completely different. (it's my code:-)

Comment: your title is now even more confusing!!! the title now mentions _two_ environments `tabular` and `tabularx` _neither of which is used in your example, which uses `tabular*`. Since you accepted a `tabularx` answer, please edit your question and title to ask about `tabularx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`tabularx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package with a modified column header definition can help:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\colorlet{light-gray}{gray!35}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*6X}
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{light-gray}
        Test  & Test & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2 \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ side\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular}&  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2 \end{tabular} \\
        \midrule
        1 & X   & X     & X & 0  & X         & X           \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

% Long column headers should not have the 'X' column type
\begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XXlXXXX}
        \toprule
        \rowcolor{light-gray}
        Test  & Test & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}A long title \\ Another long title \end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ side\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2\end{tabular}&  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Test \\ Test2 \end{tabular} \\
        \midrule
        1 & X   & X     & X & 0  & X         & X           \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i changed my tabular* to tabularx and it does not change the white spaces in between.

Comment: @Sharah I had to change more than that. See `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*6{X}}`

Comment: my apologies, just noticed the recent edits. it works well for me now, although the spacing in between the column are not as nice as before -- columns with longer title will look awkward, i might need to define the width manually unlike before

Comment: @zarko indeed, thank you. your solution was to change tabular* to tabularx, which does not make a difference to my original code. chrisma's colution changed more than that, thus solving the original problem.

Comment: @Sharah I've edited the answer to include an example with longer column titles.

Comment: i will not argue with you :-), btw, i newer see the use of the `\extracolsep{\fill}}` in`tabularx`, so i anticipated that this is known to you ...

Comment: @zarko, thanks for the explanation. my knowledge with latex is very superficial to begin with ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't mix-and-(mis)match visual metaphores: If you wish to use color (or grayscale) to emphasize the header row, don't use `\toprule` and `\midrule` *at all*. Conversely, if you prefer to use `\toprule` and `\midrule`, don't add color to the header row. Recall the time-tested mantra of (successful) designers and artists: "Less is more."

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\mycell}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}} \strut #1\strut \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\noindent       
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{7}{C}}
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
    Test  & Test & \mycell{Test \\ Test2}   
                 & \mycell{Test \\ side} 
                 & \mycell{Test \\ Test2} 
                 & \mycell{Test \\ Test2}
                 & \mycell{Test \\ Test2} \\
    1 & X & X & X & 0 & X & X \\ 
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```